# HTTP_HOST RewriteCond doesn't match and doesn't redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have something like this set up in my htaccess, I'm currently trying to redirect an old domain to a new one;

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.newsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

The problem I have, is when I go on "http://www.oldsite.com", I get no redirect.

However, right under this rule is this one, and it does redirect properly to www, what gives?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?oldsite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.newsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Indeed `^` means: in the beginning.
and `(www\.)?` with www but optionally.